# css dropdown menu on image hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, dropdown

I need help creating a simple CSS-based dropdown menu on Image Hover. I can't believe how hard it is to find a solution to the problem anywhere.

All I found somewhat close to the solution is this from W3schools:

---

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover

---

But am trying to apply to the structure below and it's NOT working.

---

```
<div class="site-wrapper-900" class="dropbtn" style="max-width: 100% !important;">

        <ul style="margin-left:0px;">
        <li><img src="#" alt=""></li>


    <li><img src="#" alt=""></li>


    <li><img src="#" alt=""></li>


    <li><img src="#" alt=""></li>


    <li><img src="#" alt=""></li>

        </ul>

</div>
```

---

It's VERY frustrating. Can you someone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: please add your CSS too

Comment: Where is the list you want to trigger? share your code HTML+CSS on jsfiddle so we can help you

Comment: Issue resolved guys. I figured it out..turned out to be a VERY simple solution: <ul class="dropdown"><li><div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div></li>